# How Could the Music Industry Go About Implementing Crypto?

Tags: protocol-design, cryptographic-hardware

So I'm currently doing the Dan Boneh online Crypto course.

In the last problem set there was a question on AACS for DVDs and wondered if a similar method could be used for music.

- Have the music industry ever attempted something along these lines?
- What are the limitations?
- Are there any crypto-systems in the early stages with potential?

I have some initial ideas about limitations; Far more music players than DVD players, far more music files than DVDs, music rarely stored physically, legal option could be obscuring this etc.

Comment: A method similar to what? Along what lines? Please make your question self-contained apart from general knowledge about the subject. Don't assume that people have read a specific book or watched a specific video or the like.

Answer (score 2):

At one point, most music legally sold digitally was protected by DRM (all iTunes music, for instance). Eventually the labels backed down and started allowing the music to be published DRM-free.

So yes the music industry has attempted this, but it encountered all of the fundamental problems with DRM and was abandoned. Crypto fundamentally can't protect you when your design involves handing over the encryption keys to the party you don't want to directly access the data.